# Localizing month name using kotlinx-datetime library

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlinx-datetime

I use the [kotlinx-datetime](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime) library to get and compare with the user's current date.

I ran into a problem that:

```kotlin
SomeInstant.toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()).month.name
```

Returns the name of the month in English, for example: *January*.

How can I change the month name for the user's locale? For example, *janvier* in French.

---

I want to use this library only, without resorting to *java.time* classes on the Java platform.